# Get value inside custom validation attribute?

Tags: c#, validationattribute

DI've created two custom validation attributes. After I've done the date validation I want to do the time validation, but to do that I need MyDate. How can I reach MyDate from inside the time validation?

My model:

```
[DateValidation()]
public DateTime MyDate { get; set;}

[TimeValidation()]
public TimeSpan MyTime { get; set;}
```

My TimeValidation:

```
public class TimeValidation: ValidationAttribute
{
    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        TimeSpan time = (TimeSpan)value;
        DateTime MyDate //How can I get this?
        // Do stuff
        // return something good
    }       
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't include the answer in your question. If no one would throw a valid answer, you would be publishing an auto-answer, but since I provided you one you should drop the answer in your question :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>If you check [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc679289(v=vs.110).aspx), it says for `IsValid` method:</strike>

> Determines whether the specified value of the object is valid.

And, about the `value` parameter of `IsValid` it says:

> value Type: System.Object The value of the object to validate.

Thus, your so-called date is the `value` and you just need to downcast it to `DateTime`:

```
DateTime MyTime = (DateTime)value;
```

### Update

> Thats not really what I was looking for. I know how to do the
>   validation with value. But in the vague example I gave you value is
>   MyTime. But I also need MyDate inside the validation of MyTime. (I
>   intentionally left out the validation of MyDate since it is working)

You can't do that. At the end of the day, you're implementing an attribute and attributes are a type metadata detail. In other words: they can't know the object to which they're applied to.

What you need is the [`IsValid(object, ValidationContext)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd730022(v=vs.110).aspx) overload, and the `ValidationContext` will give you the object to validate as the `ObjectInstance` property.

Thus, you can access the other property using reflection:

```
DateTime MyDate = (DateTime)validationContext.ObjectInstance.GetType()
                    .GetProperty("MyDate", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
                    .GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance);
```

I would also add an argument to `TimeValidation` attribute called `relatedPropertyName` in order to don't hardcode the related property name.

Comment: Thats not really what I was looking for. I know how to do the validation with value. But in the vague example I gave you value is MyTime. But I also need MyDate inside the validation of MyTime. (I intentionally left out the validation of MyDate since it is working)

Comment: Thats more like it :) But, I don't get any value. Please see update in question

Comment: Nevermind. I'm stupid. Thank you so much for the help!